# Sending a slash through mysql

Tags: php, mysql, escaping

I'm not sure why this has stumped me. I have the following code

```
$website = "http://www.google.com";
$name = "Person";

if(!empty($website) {
   $name = "[url=$website]$name[/url]"; 
}
```

Then i try to insert that into mysql. I tried adding mysql_real_escape_string to both $website and $name (after the if statement), thinking the "/url" might also cause problems.

```
$name       = mysql_real_escape_string($name);
```

Still no luck though. Any advice? What am I missing? It's giving me this error

"Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '/', expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING"

Comment: What is the problem? What happens?

Comment: `mysql_real_escape_string` should protect the string regardless of what happens. If you still have issues, it could be a misapplication of `mysql_real_escape_string` (how do you call it?) or a script misreading the correct data stored in the database (how do you read it?).

Comment: Could you provide the SQL query and the error you get?

Comment: Sorry about that, added the parse error I'm getting now.

Comment: You tryed "adding" mysql_real_escape_string? What do you mean by that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try

```
if(!empty($website)) {
   $name = "[url={$website}]{$name}[/url]"; 
}
```

then use,

```
mysql_real_escape_string ($name);
```

Comment: Holy crap, that worked. Can you let me know why? What did the brackets do?

Comment: Well, bracket inside quotes indicates php about variables. That means, zend engines deals it as a php variable and include its value. Sometimes, without brackets it mess up with other stuff.

Comment: Since { can not be escaped, this syntax will only be recognised when the $ immediately follows the {. Please refer, http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php for more info.

Comment: You should be doing this anyway, but it won't actually escape anything in the string you have provided, so won't help. Please see my or tdammers answer below.

Answer (score 1):

This is a PHP syntax problem.
The parser thinks $name[ is the start of a array reference you have to add curly bracelets to tell the parser where the variable name starts and end:
"[url={$website}]{$name}[/url]"

Answer (score 0):

There wont be any problem at all. When reading from database you should then put `stripslashes()` around your value.
e.g.

```
$query = "SELECT field FROM table";
$row = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query));

echo(stripslashes($row['field']));
```

And your output will be the same like **YOUR** input.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're quoting values you send into a query, like so:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table (column) VALUES ('$value')";
```

Whatever is in $value gets passed into the query. If you leave out the quotes, bad things may happen even if you use `mysql_real_escape_string()`. Inside strings, forward slashes do not have any special meaning in MySQL, and so `mysql_real_escape_string()` leaves them intact. This is not a bug, but the documented, correct behaviour. Basically, you need to quote all values in your query.

However, the best solution IMHO is to use PDO and its parametrized queries instead of the mysql_XXX API. It's a bit more complicated (not much though), and it allows you to pass parameters into a query through an associative array, doing all the escaping and quoting you need for you.

Answer (score 0):

Are you putting quotes around the value you want to insert? This will work

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column_name)
VALUES ('[url=$website]http://www.google.com[/url]')
```

This will fail

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column_name)
VALUES ([url=$website]http://www.google.com[/url])
```

So you might have in you php

```
$query = "INSERT INTO table_name (column_name) VALUES ('$name')";
// DO MYSQL_QUERY
```